# How to call child class methods using parent class object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a bit new to Python inheritance. I have a code something like this

```
class Parent(object):
'''
Class for Parent
'''

def __init__(self, host, user, password):
    self.host = host
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.child = Child()

def method1(self,param1, param2, param3):
    self.child.method1(param1, param2, param3)
```

The below is the child class. Both parent and child classes are in the same file

```
class Child(Parent):
'''
Class for Child
'''
  def __init__(self):
    super(Child).__init__()

  def method1(self, param1, param2, param3):
    // My actual code will be here
```

Now, I have another python script where I would initialize the parent object and call method1

```
 client = Parent(host, user, password)
 client.method1(param1, param2, param3)
```

With the above approach, I am expecting that the method1 of Child will get executed. But it is not. I am getting the following error

```
 TypeError: super() takes at most 1 argument (0 given)
```

What is the solution for this..? Where am I doing wrong..?

Comment: It was actually there in my code. Edited the question now. The error is still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with the help of a Singleton class. This is what I have done. This is the parent class.

```
class Parent(object):
'''
Class for Parent
'''

def __init__(self, host, user, password):
    self.host = host
    self.user = user
    self.password = password

def helper_method1():
    // Implementation
```

Then I've created a singleton class

```
class ParentObjMgr(object):
    '''
    A Singleton that stores the objects of different child classes.
    The child class needs to be instantiated here.
    This class needs to be instantiated in the caller.
    '''
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self._host = host
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
        self._child1 = None
        self._child2 = None

    def get_child1(self):
        if not self._child1:
            self._child1 = Child1(self._host, self._user, self._password)
        return self._child1

    def get_child2(self):
        if not self._child2:
            self._child2 = Child2(self._host, self._user, self._password)
        return self._child2
```

Now I will implement child classes

```
class Child1(Parent):
    // Implementation

class Child2(Parent):
    // Implementation
    self.helper_method1()
```

Now in the caller, I would do this

```
parent_object_mgr=ParentObjMgr(self.host, self.user, self.password)                  
child1=parent_object_mgr.get_child1()
child2=parent_object_mgr.get_child2()
```

This is how I have managed to access all the child class objects with the help of a single class object. Now, I don't have to instantiate the child classes, wherever they are being called and that is what I was looking for. Please let me know if it is an efficient solution (or) is there anything I need to do to improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) takes two arguments, as the error message explains. You use it like this:

```
super(Child, self).__init__()
```

However, you also have to pass along all the required arguments to `__init__`. Since your `Parent` takes a `host`, `user`, and `password`, you need these to `super` the initializer. So you probably want something like this in `Child`:

```
def __init__(self, host, user, password):
    super(Child, self).__init__(host, user, password)
```

Although since `Child.__init__` doesn't actually do anything besides try to `super`, the simpler thing to do is to just not override `__init__` in the first place.

At any rate, once you solve the `super` problem, either way, you're just going to have an infinite recursion—the `Parent` creates a `Child()`, which supers the `Parent` constructor and therefore creates another `Child()`, and so on until you get an exception.

In fact, your design is very weird. It's rare that an object needs to hold a reference to (much less create) an instance of one of its subclasses. Normally, you just want to use inheritance as inheritance. Something like this:

```
class Parent(object):
    '''
    Class for Parent
    '''

    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.child = Child()

class Child(Parent):
    def method1(self, param1, param2, param3):
        # actual code here
```

Now, if you create a `child = Child(host, user, password)`, you can call `child.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)` on it. If you want to provide a default implementation in `Parent`, you can. You can even make it a pre- or post-implementation that `Child` and any other children call via `super` before or after their own code. Which one you actually want is impossible to say with this toy model, but for real classes it's usually pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @abarnert. You are right. After solving the super, it went to recursive loop. The idea behind this approach is that I don't want to create objects for the child classes. If I have multiple childs, then I would end up creating objects for all of it. Instead if there is a way to create just the parent object and then use it for all the methods in the child classes, then that would be great.

Comment: @user3157132 That doesn't make much sense. If the child classes aren't being instantiated, why do they exist in the first place? This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); if you can explain what you're actually trying to do, or just give  an example with real semantics that makes it obvious, that would really help.

Comment: I am trying to automate a product testing, which has multiple components. To test these components, first I need to login to the product. This part should go to Parent class. Individual component testing will go to component classes (child classes) after getting the login session object from the parent class. All of this will be a part of a library. Now I will import this library in some other python script. So in order to call these libraries, I would need to instantiate all the component classes (child classes). I am trying to avoid this and use only parent object to call the child methods.

Comment: @user3157132 Either you have child objects—in which case they have to be instantiated somewhere—or you don't—in which case you just have a bunch of functions and/or parent methods. You can't call a method on a child object without a child object. Meanwhile, if the parent just instantiates and manages a bunch of things, that's fine—but in that case, why are they inheriting from the parent in the first place?

Comment: I am not calling a child method without the child object. I am instantiating the child class, in the parent class (self.child = Child()) and then calling the child methods on top of that. But this is leading to recursive loop.

Comment: @user3157132 OK, is there a reason for the `Child` to be a subclass of `Parent`?

Comment: Yes, I need logon session variable from the parent class to be used in the child classes...

Comment: @user3157132 Just have it pass either `self` or `self.logon_session` to each instance's constructor. Not only do you not need inheritance just to share a value, it doesn't even _help_ you share a value